# Ubuntu 23.04 Won't Boot into GUI and Package Installations Fail Due to Broken Dependencies

Tags: package-management, 23.04

Broken Dependencies Prevent ubuntu Desktop Reinstall too and can´t even install ssh.

I already tried ¨sudo apt --fix-broken install, sudo dpkg --configure -a, and sudo apt autoremove¨

¨Welcome to Ubuntu 23.04 (GNU/Linux 6.0.6-1-surface x86_64)

```
* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Last login: Tue Nov 28 22:06:39 PST 2023 on tty1
[username]@surface:~$ sudo apt install -y openssh-server
[sudo] password for [username]:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (>= 1:8.9p1-1ubuntu0.4) but 1:8.9p1-1ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                 Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
¨
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `apt policy openssh-server`. The use of `-y` is not recommended as you are telling the system "do it whatever the consequences!" Your are fortunate that the consequences seem minor.